# Encountered `ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager` though `spring-jdbc` was defined in `gradle` file

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-jdbc

I am using spring version `5.2.3.RELEASE` running on JDK 8, but during runtime I am getting the below error

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class  ... ... Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcTransactionManager`

Even though I have declared the below in my `build.gradle` file
`implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: springframeworkVersion`

Full build.gradle is below

```
    plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    }
    
    group = 'org.temp'
    version = ''
    
    repositories {
    
        maven {
            url 'https://ost1v.enp.aramco.com.sa:8443/repository/maven-central'
            credentials {
                username mavenuser
                password mavenpassword
            }
        }
    
        maven {
            url 'https://ost1v.enp.aramco.com.sa:8443/repository/maven-jcenter'
            credentials {
                username mavenuser
                password mavenpassword
            }
        }
    
    
        maven {
            url 'https://ost1v.enp.aramco.com.sa:8443/repository/maven-releases'
            credentials {
                username mavenuser
                password mavenpassword
            }
        }
    
        maven {
            url 'https://ost1v.enp.aramco.com.sa:8443/repository/maven-jaspersoft-3rd-party-ce'
            credentials {
                username mavenuser
                password mavenpassword
            }
        }
    
    
    }
    
    
    ext {
    
        slf4jVersion = '1.7.25'
        logbackVersion = '1.3.0-alpha10'
    
        jacksonDatabindVersion = '2.11.1'  //2.10.1, change it to 2.12.6
    
        springframeworkVersion = '5.3.23'
        //springframeworkVersion = '5.2.3.RELEASE' - This was commented to fix the problem
        //springSecurityVersion = '5.3.8.RELEASE'
        springSecurityVersion = '5.3.3.RELEASE'
    
    
        mybatisVersion = '3.5.6'
        mybatisJsr310 = '1.0.2'
        mybatisSpringVersion = '1.3.2'
    
        oracleJdbcVersion = '19.3.0.0'
        oracleSpatialVersion = '12.1.0.2'
        oracleXdbVersion = '12.2.1.2'
    
        lombokVersion = '1.16.20'
    
    
        commonsCollectionsVersion = '4.1'
        commonsIOVersion = '2.7'
        commonsLangVersion = '3.7'
        commonsFileuploadVersion = '1.4'
        commonsHttpclientVersion = '4.5.10'
        commonsExecVersion = '1.3'
        commonsBeanutilsVersion = '1.9.4'
    
        junitVersion = '4.12'
        mockitoVersion = '2.16.0'
        powermockVersion = '1.7.3'
    
        jasyptVersion = '1.9.2'
        hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
    
        bouncyCastleVersion = '1.64'
        //tokenServiceVersion = '2.0'
        tokenServiceVersion = '1.6-SNAPSHOT'
    
        jsonPathVersion = '2.4.0'
    
        geotoolsVersion = '18.2'
    
        itextVersion = '2.1.7.js4'
    
        jasperReportsVersion = '6.12.2'
        batikVersion = '1.13'
        fopVersion = '2.2'
    
        javaxMail = '1.5.6'
        freeMarker = '2.3.28'
        subethamail = '3.1.7'
    
    }
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.5'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.5.5'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.5'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: springframeworkVersion
        implementation group:  'org.mybatis.spring.boot',name:'mybatis-spring-boot-starter',version:'2.2.2'
        implementation group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: commonsBeanutilsVersion
        implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: commonsCollectionsVersion
        implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: commonsIOVersion
        implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: commonsLangVersion
        implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: commonsFileuploadVersion
        implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: commonsExecVersion
        implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: commonsHttpclientVersion
        implementation group: 'com.oracle.ojdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: oracleJdbcVersion
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: springSecurityVersion
    
    
    
        // implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: logbackVersion
        // implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: logbackVersion
    
    
    
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis
        implementation group: 'org.mybatis', name: 'mybatis', version: '3.5.6'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.minidev/json-smart
        //implementation group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '2.3'
    
    
        implementation group: 'org.mybatis', name: 'mybatis-spring', version: '2.0.0'
        implementation group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
        implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: bouncyCastleVersion
    
        implementation group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.5'  // 1.4.5
    
        compileOnly  fileTree(dir: 'dependencies/documentum/Shared', include: '*.jar')
    
    
        testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitVersion
        testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: springframeworkVersion
        testImplementation group: 'org.subethamail', name: 'subethasmtp', version: subethamail
    
        testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: mockitoVersion
        testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: hamcrestVersion
    
        testImplementation group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt', version: jasyptVersion
        testImplementation group: 'org.jasypt', name: 'jasypt-spring31', version: jasyptVersion
    
        //testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: springSecurityVersion
        //implementation group: 'com.github.albfernandez', name: 'itext2', version: '2.1.9'
        implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.12.2'
        testImplementation group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: jsonPathVersion
    
        //compile group: 'com.github.albfernandez', name: 'itext2', version: '2.1.9'
        //compile (group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.7.1') {exclude group: 'com.lowagie', module: "itext"}
    
    
    }
    
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

Comment: Can you please include the full build.gradle in your question?

Answer (score 1):

There was a version mismatch, `spring-jdbc` was pointing to version `5.2.3.RELEASE`, after changing its version to match with the rest of spring libraries which were of version `5.3.23`, the problem was resolved.

Rest of the spring libraries of version `5.3.23` were automatically downloaded as sub dependencies of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.5`. I was explicity downloading the `spring-jdbc` version and it was pointing to an older version.